# Python result of a strange function, that I can't reproduce in another language

Tags: python

My python function :

```
def searchMAX(Dict):
    v=list(Dict.values())
    return list(Dict.keys())[v.index(max(v))]
```

I can't reproduce it in java to understand what's its output

If I do :

```
myDico ={0:0.0}
myDico.update({1:1.2}) 
myDico.update({2:11.2}) 
myDico.update({3:17.2})
myMax = searchMAX(myDico)
print(*myMax, sep='\n')
```

I have this error :

```
TypeError: print() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

With `print(myMax, sep'\n')` only retun **3** not a list :( ?

Comment: it's the same as `max(Dict.items(), key=lambda item:item[1])[0]`.

Comment: @das-g, I modifed it, but I've not writting the original function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Dict` is a Python `dict` then:

```
v = list(Dict.values())
```

make a list of the iterator over the values of `Dict` and assings it to `v`

Then

```
return list(Dict.keys())[v.index(max(v))]
```

make a list of the keys of `Dict` and and **returns the key that has the maximum value associated with it** by finding the index of the maximum value (`v.index(max(v))`) and using that index on the list.

Thus `searchMAX` return a key which in your case is always an integer and you cannot pass that to print() with a `*`. You should do:

```
print(Max, sep='\n')
```

Comment: A good answer explaining `*` and `**` is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters#36908).

Comment: And if I understand more, it return ONLY an index ? Not a list as I see in the code ?

Comment: @HarryCotte no it returns a key, that key is the integer `3` from `{3: 17.2}`

Comment: @Anthon thank you. I will try to make the java equivalent now.